# Editing a Slider from w3school

Tags: javascript, slider

So I'm trying to learn JavaScript but in the mean time I'm manipulating other's code, such as w3school's. I thought I could manage this but am struggling.

I'm trying to remove anything to do with the dot, numbering and caption from this  script. I can work through process of elimination but I'd rather not end up with some messy script.

This is a link to the complete code https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

Thank you in advance..

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";  
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just remove anything that uses `dots`. Most of the changes that you want to do are removing elements from the HTML anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not that hard :)
Here you have it:

```
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>

</div>
<br>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

Furthermore you might want to remove the unnecesary css classes.

Comment: thanks very much, I did try removing anything with dots involved in it but I seemed to have half of a method left over.

I can sort the CSS and html, thanks for your help, going to take a closer look at the differences to see where I was going wrong :)

Comment: Done :) sorry I didn't realize that 'accepting' was a thing :D